# Bootstrap not working in PDF rendering

Tags: visualforce, pdf, bootstrap

Following is my code which is working fine as a VF page on preview, but no styling adding on rendering as PDF `renderAs="PDF"`. Let me know what I am doing wrong as I am new to the platform.

**Code -**

```
<apex:page>
  <!-- Adding CSS -->
  <!-- <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS092, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}" /> -->

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
</div>
</div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: try to include your Bootstrap file in static resource and then reference them .

Comment: @TusharSharma I added bootstrap `bootstrap-3.3.5-dist.zip` as a static resource and using like - `<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, 'bootstrap-3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css')}" />
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, 'bootstrap-3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')}" />` but stylesheet is not coming

Comment: @TusharSharma `bootstrap` is the name of my static folder

Comment: When you remove render as pdf then bootstrap is available. Also keep in mind that there many css which will not work with `renderAs=pdf`

Comment: @TusharSharma I am not rendering it in PDF I am only testing as VF first like - http://pastebin.com/v1F0SvtX

Comment: @TusharSharma I am including https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.3.5/bootstrap-3.3.5-dist.zip as a `bootstrap` name static resource

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not going to be able to render PDFs properly that were created with Bootstrap. The [Flying Saucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) Render engine used by Salesforce only supports CSS 2.1 and HTML 4.1

Comment: To add to this, http://www.spurdoc.com will work with bootstrap and create a PDF for you. Only downside is you have to expose the VF page to a public site and maybe create a urlparam key to ensure the page will not display without it to protect the contents (somewhat)

Comment: Who knows, perhaps the http://www.spurdoc.com engine will be what Salesforce winds up finding a way to support in some manner as a means of enabling PDF support for HTML5 and Lightning pages. Will be interesting to see what kind of support for PDFs they eventually come up with.

Comment: @crmprogdev Wow thanks for the info ..it really consumed my whole day with hit and trial ..just out of curiosity even newly `SLDS` also not supported if I replace it with `bootstrap` ?

Comment: That's correct. No support for PDFs with Lightning. You'll find it in the [release notes here](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/lex_gaps_limitations_data_access.htm) under "working with data".